# How do you debug app in Xcode and Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am working on a keyboard app and I come from a PHP background. I was asked to see if I can get long presses working on the keyboard (when you hold down on A for instance, all the accents should show).

I have tried a few things and now when you press on A, it acts like something is firing off, but fails, and the keyboard switches to the default emoji board instead.

The debug window in Xcode is blank. There doesn't seem to be an active console log like you would use with JavaScript, so I am completely stumped on how I can figure out what's happening. If I could see that it's failing on a certain function, then I would be able to know where to start fixing problems.

Also, I tried using breakpoints but they never were hit.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint

Comment: Is that any difference than a regular breakpoint because they aren't wotking

Comment: An exception breakpoint will be called at any crash, you don't place it into your code like a regular breakpoint. If it doesn't show you the line of the code that is causing the error than it's not a bug, just a mistake.

Comment: Ok thanks will give that a try

Comment: Well I added the exception, though nothing happened or was logged even though there was a crash when performing a long press on one of the keyboard keys..

Comment: What make you think there's a crash? Did the app quit, hang?

Comment: It's a keyboard app so you select the keyboard which works and you can use it but when you press and hold on a letter like A, the keyboard switches back to the default keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like there isn't a crash

Comment: Probably right but that's my problem. I can't tell what is and what isn't happening because I can't figure out how to create some logs or errors or something to show if something is not being assigned or if a library/framework is missing.